# How do get maximum count grouped by element in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, max, pandas-groupby

I have data grouped by tow columns [CustomerID,cluster] like this:

```
CustomerIDClustered.groupby(['CustomerID','cluster']).count()


                    Count
CustomerID cluster       
1893       0            1
           1            2
           2            5
           3            1
2304       2            3
           3            1
2655       0            1
           2            1
2850       1            1
           2            1
           3            1
3648       0            1
```

I need assign most frequent cluster to the customer id

For Example:

1. 1893->2 (2 appear in cluster more than other clusters)
2. 2304->2
3. 2655->1

Comment: Please post your data as code and **not as an image**. Furthermore `cluster==1` does not appear in `CustomerID==2655`. And what do you want to do with duplicates?

Comment: I think it would be better to provide assistance like @jezrael than negative rating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('Count', ascending=False).reset_index().drop_duplicates('CustomerID')
```

Similar solution, only filter by first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.sort_values('Count', ascending=False)
df = df[~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated()].reset_index()
print (df)
   CustomerID  cluster  Count
0        1893        2      5
1        2304        2      3
2        2655        0      1
3        2850        1      1
4        3648        0      1
```